# Position on onBindViewHolder() doesn't get updated with item deletion

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I have a `recyclerview` displaying my data. In my adapter class, inside `onBindViewHolder()`, I have created a listener for a button which deletes a row on click. The first time works just fine, but if I try to delete an item the position value is the same as if the size of the list hasn't changed.

So for example I have a 4 item list. I delete the 3rd item (with index 2). The 4th item goes in the 3rd slot and the size of the list becomes 3. If I try to delete the 3rd item, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as the items position hasn't been updated and its index is still 3, whereas the size is 3.

Here is the code of part of my `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ItemRegistered item = registeredList.get(position);
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == 0) {
            final RegisteredViewHolder registeredViewHolder = (RegisteredViewHolder) holder;
            registeredViewHolder.course.setText(item.getCourse());

            registeredViewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                                    if (mButtonClickListener != null) {

                                        Log.d("i", Integer.toString(position));
                                        Log.d("list size:", Integer.toString(registeredList.size()));

                                        final String title = registeredList.get(position).getCourse();
                                        mButtonClickListener.onButtonClicked(title);
                                    }

                                    registeredList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    //No button clicked
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(registeredViewHolder.course.getContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Jeni të sigurtë që doni të çregjistroheni?").setPositiveButton("Po", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("Jo", dialogClickListener).show();

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing item from list and then notify the adapter.

that is replace this lines...

```
registeredList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

with `remove(position);`

now just make a method and add the logic..

```
public void remove(int position){
registeredList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
// to animate the list deletion                
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
}
```

hope it helps :)